# Concerns about handing over assests

Tags: business, client-relations

I have a sticky situation and I'm not quite sure how to deal with it.

As part of branding a company for a friend/client I have created some cartoon type characters (as well a logo, fonts, colours, feel and all the other branding stuff). Now this is a good friend so I'm not necessarily concerned about losing business but he's involved someone else to do some facebook marketing. This third party wants all the individual assets.

I'm doing all this work at a reasonable rate and would like to retain control of the artwork used.

As this is a friend I have offered to create backgrounds for the ads for free when ordinarily I would be negotiating a better rate for handing over the constituent parts of my design work.

The third party is pressing for the parts so I would welcome any input on how to proceed and what my expectations should be.

Thanks.

Comment: If it is truly a "friend" can't you just speak to them and voice your concerns?

Comment: I have broached the subject but haven't gone as far as explaining the finance side of things. 
The reason for asking the question was to make sure I wasn't being unreasonable first.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have your answer right there in your question. I would suggrest that you tell your friend/client:

> I'm doing all this work at a reasonable rate and would like to retain control of the artwork used. As you are friend I have offered to create backgrounds for the ads for free when ordinarily I would be negotiating a much higher rate for handing over the constituent parts of my design work.

And then maybe follow with

> I'm sure you understand. I'd be fine handing this over to your 3rd part marketing person but I do have to ask you for a market-rate fee to do so.

They may understand, they may not. That is the risk we always take doing work for friends at a 'friend rate'.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not happy with asking for market rate (he's a good friend) I'll just insist on doing the ads I think. I'll suggest the 3rd party mocks them up and I'll supply the images with out text. I feel like that's probably the best way around it.

Comment: @Steve1974 though you don't have to *ask* for it, I do strongly feel that it is imperative your friend understand what the going rate is for this type of work. It's fine that he gets a great 'friends discount' but it's important you get something in return (control) and I think a good friend will understand that.